# Prestashop Admin performance page and Information page saying not found

Tags: prestashop, admin

I am using prestashop version 1.7.3.2 Now my admin Performance  page and Information page shows `page not found` message. How can I fix this?[image]

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I use the same version and it works just fine. What did you do before it gone? What version of PHP are you using? Did you enable a debug mode?

Comment: Its work for me for past weeks, I enabled debug mode via that page. Recently I installed some modules. I uninstalled that modules and checked but not working.

Comment: These admin pages are working via any DB data? My newly installed modules altered that DB details? And one more thing I deleted the class_index file in the cache folder to work my override. Is that cause this issue?

Comment: Yes, your module could change tabs routes URL. Look into your browser URL bar and check if URL's are correct. Information should be your_domain/index.php/configure/advanced/system_information, and Performance should be your_module/index.php/configure/advanced/performance. And you can even put it to your browser and check results

Comment: This is my Performance URL: 
domain.com/admin****/index.php?controller=AdminPerformance&token=******

Comment: So it seems that the problem is there. Did you update your store from the previous version or you install it with the current one? If you would use this one domain.com/admin****/index.php/configure/advanced/performance?_token=****** I think it will be display

Comment: Thanks. The URL you specified above is working. But in the menu it showing another URL (I specified above.)
My store was not updated from previous Prestashop version. I install it with current version.