# presta shop nginx 404

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm new to Prestashop.

I installed it on nginx webserver, and in the admin area of presta 2 links are not working:

```
 admin348u/index.php/configure/advanced/performance?_token=Sln8hoDNuxn04zZ_yP13sZQRYs1P13vNidJ2ES2mGag
```

and

```
 admin348u/index.php/configure/advanced/system_information?_token=Sln8hoDNuxn04zZ_yP13sZQRYs1P13vNidJ2ES2mGag
```

So these are the advanced settings> performance and information pages.

I'm receiving a 404 error page.

I have no idea what this is, could it be nginx related?

Another person n the internet had the same problem:

[Prestashop Admin performance page and Information page saying not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607713/prestashop-admin-performance-page-and-information-page-saying-not-found)

But there is no real solution posted.

Comment: Maybe, because 404 is related to "not found".

Answer (score 1):

You need a specific configuration for your backend as Nginx is working pretty much differently from Apache with this part.
Some pages of Prestashop 1.7 are written with Symfony, which mean you better stick to the recommended configuration and use Apache here sadly.

We tryed to do some work about that with Prestashop (see here https://github.com/MattLoyeD/Prestashop-Nginx ) but as far as I know it's not fully working.

Prestashop's has published a file in their repository for example, if you wanna try : https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/docs/server_config/nginx.conf.dist

Comment: i solved it by replacing: # Symfony controllers
     53     #location ~ /(international|_profiler|module\/catalog|product|configure|feature|attribute|supplier|combination|specific-price)/(.*)$ {
     54     #   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args $admin_dir/index.php$is_args$args;
     55     #}
(FOUND ON INTERNET)  with: location /admin831e5ib8e/ {
     58         if (!-e $request_filename) {
     59            rewrite ^/.*$ /admin831e5ib8e/index.php last; #Change this to your admin folder
     60         }
     61     } so it was really just a rewrite issue